# different class h4 for wordpress css footer customization

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm building a site for a client where I'm looking to alter the h4 tag in the footer. The theme I'm using is a premium purchased theme however when customize the h4 tag for the footer div widget class. It alters every h4 element within the entire body.

The same happens with boarder-underline class. once i customize it with css every underline boarder class reflects the same.

looking for suggestions which can help separate the footer h4 and other elements into a new class to stop the alterations happening within the body.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please add the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

If your footer has a class, you could target that class.

```
h4 {
    // all h4 styles.
}
.footer h4 {
    // scoped h4 styles.
    color: #dadada
}
```